# Road infrastructure efficiency measurement

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, road, infrastructure

Is there any tool/script that shows the goodness of road infrastructure. For example, if you want to compare which of the two cities road network is better.

Comment: I'm not sure of any road efficiency tools but some methodologies exist. Google 'road efficiency' and you'll get some results.

Answer (score 1):

It depends heavily on what you mean by "goodness" and "better". There are two options:

1. Create a remote sensing tool to analyze road characteristics based on satellite or aerial imagery. If you don't immediately know how to do this then I would warn you that it will take a very long time to learn. A tool like this might exist already, although it's likely not been made public.
2. Find a CSV/shapefile/whatever of city roads that includes quality assessment, then symbolize your layer according to that field. This is of course contingent on that data existing in the first place.